# draw transparent line?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm drawing an ellipse.  I want the line color to be a percentage transparent.  I've found plenty of examples for setting the background transparent, but I want the line color itself to be say 50% transparent.  Is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what library you're using to draw?

Comment: Show the code you have so far for drawing the ellipse.

Comment: This question could probably be reopened if you show us the code - we aren't very good at debugging nonexistent code.

Comment: I've added the code.  Can this question be reopened, please?

Comment: Wouldn't you just use CGContextSetAlpha?  (Or specify an alpha component in CGContextSetStrokeColor?  Or use CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha and use the resulting color in CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't set the alpha value of the green color

set an alpha of 0.5 and you got it

one way would be to switch

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
```

for

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
```